# Can not update lambda runtime through AWS CLI

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I'm trying to update lambda runtime, using AWS CLI, with the following command:

`aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name <func_name> --runtime nodejs4.3`

But I get an error:

`Unknown options: --runtime, nodejs4.3`

AWS version is as follows:
`aws-cli/1.9.6 Python/3.5.0 Windows/7 botocore/1.3.6`

Comment: What shell are you running aws cli from?  Have you tried putting the `--runtime` operand before `--function-name`?

Comment: Please run `aws --version` and edit your question to include the output from that command.

Comment: @BaileyS Changing options order still result in the same error.

Comment: @MarkB I've added aws version to question.

Comment: Have you tried updating to the latest version of the AWS CLI?

Comment: @MarkB Yes, sure. Version posted in question is a result of update

Comment: @Minstel the version in your output is not the latest version.

Comment: @MarkB Hm... For update I ran `pip install --upgrade awscli`, and it worked fine, with no errors.

Comment: @Minstel For reference, the latest version is 1.10.67

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option is available from [aws cli 1.10.19](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.rst#11019) so you need to upgrade at least to this version of newer

> feature:`lambda`: Added support for setting the function runtime as nodejs4.3, as well as updating function configuration to set the runtime.

On Windows, download and run either the 64 bit installer (https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/AWSCLI64.msi) or the 32 bit installer (https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/AWSCLI32.msi).

Comment: Ok, thank you) Maybe there is smth with update process on my machine, so I failed to obtain the latest version when upgraiding through console.